# Flyway migration using IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, migration, flyway

I have no prior experience with IntelliJ IDEA and Flyway and now I have got several difficulties while generating flyway migration file in IntelliJ IDEA. On the other hand, after making some search, I saw a plugin called [Flyway Migration Creation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8597-flyway-migration-creation). However, there is not enough information about the plugin and its capabilities on its page or internet.

So, could you please clarify me how should I use hat plugin and is it able to generate migration.sql from the corresponding java class (entity or model).

Comment: Does anybody else has ever generated Flyway Migration in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Good question, it never worked for me either